# It is my first time to VERB or VERB-ing

Tags: phrase-usage

From a sentence written by a student:

> It was my first time to visit China.

It sounds wrong to me, but using **visiting** only sounds slightly better. Which one is correct?

Comment: With this verb, both forms are correct and sound natural.

Comment: I agree, _visiting_ is better, and _to visit_ sounds odd. I have a hard time explaining why, though.

Comment: *It was my first visit to China* is how most native speakers would say it.

Answer (score 4):

No - that doesn't sound odd at all. In fact it sounds perfectly fine to me.

More examples

1. It was my first time to stand on a stage and give a speech.
2. It was my first time to get to see any celebrity in person.

Note the following examples

It was my first time to ride a horse (Here i think you expressing your feeling before you actually rode the horse)

But when you say

It was my first time riding a horse (Here i think you expressing your feeling when you have ridden the horse)

Comment: "My first time to stand..." The infinitive is stiffly formal. In casual speech most native speakers would say something like "It was the first time I ever stood on a stage and gave a speech" or "It was my first time ever standing on a stage and giving a speech".

Comment: I've found that to use the infinitive form could make the sentence confusing because your first example can mean either "It was my first time I was going to stand on a stage and give a speech" or "It was my first time I was standing on a stage and giving a speech", so, to get rid of this confusion, I think it'd be much better to use its gerund form as in "It was my first time standing on a stage and giving a speech".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Don't you think to use the infinitive instead of the gerund might be very confusing without context as I've said in my comment?